# cannot find module 'pouchdb', works on mac, but not on windows

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm taking over an ionic project that works on my mates mac. Clean windows 10 PC with ionic/cordova/python installed. The project runs, but the following error occurs. I've tried multiple different ways of including pouchdb within the project (using @types/ using older versions, using require instead of import, deleting and reinstalling node modules etc), and I can't find any way around this error. I've reverted all the changes I made. The following code works on my mates mac.

I also just checked with him on versions. I'm running all the same versions of node/python/ionic etc.

[image: error]

package.json

```
{
    "name": "camara2",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@types/pouchdb": "6.3.2",
        "ajv": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cropperjs": "^1.4.1",
        "ionic": "^4.6.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "json-circular-stringify": "0.0.1",
        "mrz": "^3.1.0",
        "newtondev-mrz-parser": "^1.1.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "tesseract.js": "^1.0.10",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
        "@ionic/lab": "1.0.6",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-console": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "browser",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

import

```
//import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: Did you try to add pouchdb to your dependencies?

Comment: It's there `"@types/pouchdb": "6.3.2",` . I also tried using the dependency without @types it also doesn't work.

Comment: `"@types/pouchdb": "6.3.2"` isn't the module. It's only the typings for typescript. "This package contains type definitions for pouchdb" https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pouchdb

Comment: Does he have a directory `pouchdb` in his `node_modules` and do you have this directory? Does he have the paths configured in his tsconfig.js and do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install PouchDB with

```
npm install --save pouchdb
```

`@types/pouchdb` isn't the actual module. It's only the typings for typescript.You need both modules.

Comment: You should install pouchdb and @types/pouchdb

Comment: You seem to have installed only `@types/pouchdb` - do `npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb`